# Select and separate column name from database passed in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Microsoft SQL Server (2016)

I have a variable passed into my procedure: `@param_n_fileName`

The variable contains column name in this format (`student_id+year+student_name`)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateQueue] 
    (@param_n_studentID VARCHAR(50),
     @param_n_studentName VARCHAR(50),
     @param_n_databaseName VARCHAR(50))
```

I am not sure how to split these column names and then select the value of these columns.

The statement below didn't work

```
DECLARE @column_Value NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @column_Value = (SELECT STRING_SPLIT(@param_n_studentName) 
                     FROM dbo.studentTable)
```

Once I have the value of those columns then I need to save those values in a different table

i.e (column1_value+column2_value)

So far I did this

```
INSERT INTO student.dbo.studentTable (student_id, year, student_name) 
    SELECT student_id, year, @column_value 
    FROM dbo.studentTable
    WHERE [student_id] IN (SELECT value 
                           FROM STRING_SPLIT(@param_n_studentID, ',') 
                           WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '')
```

Comment: `dynamic sql` it is

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a tag for the actual database platform you're using would help us help you. [Why Should I Tag My RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms/)

Comment: @EricBrandt sorry it's Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: Seems like a terrible design - going to cause no end of issues.

Comment: When you say passed as student_id+year+student_name is the `+` sign the seperator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you want dynamic sql, something like the following:

```
declare @param_n_fileName nvarchar(max) = 'student_id+year+student_name'

set @param_n_fileName = (select replace(@param_n_filename, '+', ', '))

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select ' + @param_n_filename + ' from studentTable'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

You don't need `string_split()` because `replace()` works just fine.

Comment: @param_n_fileName is a strange name for a string with column names in it, but oh well.